# Dúvida sobre o UPDATE (Editar.php)

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de Cadastro de Processos para a Prefeitura da minha cidade e me veio uma questão.

É possível, depois de registrar os dados, editar apenas uma vez os dados? Apenas uma, depois disso é "ineditável".

Segue o código de edição, caso alguém tenha alguma ideia!

```html
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

// Recebe o id do cliente do cliente via GET
$id_cliente = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

// Valida se existe um id e se ele é numérico
if (!empty($id_cliente) && is_numeric($id_cliente)):

 // Captura os dados do cliente solicitado
 $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
 $sql = 'SELECT id, numero, nome, status, setor1, setor2, data1, observ1, setor3, setor4, data2, observ2, setor5, setor6, data3, observ3 FROM processos WHERE id = :id';
 $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
 $stm->bindValue(':id', $id_cliente);
 $stm->execute();
 $cliente = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

endif;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Edição de Processo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  <style type="text/css">
 <!--
body {
 background-image: url("./img/bg.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
<!---->
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container'>
  <fieldset>
   <legend><h1>Formulário - Edição de Processo</h1></legend>
   
   <?php if(empty($cliente)):?>
    <h3 class="text-center text-danger">Processo não encontrado!</h3>
   <?php else: ?>
    <form action="all_processo.php" method="post" id='form-contato' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <div class="row">
     
         <p><div class='form-group'>
     <label for='numero'>Número do Processo</label>
     <input type='number' class='form-control' id='numero' name='numero' value="<?=$cliente->numero?>" placeholder='Informe o Número do Processo'>
     <span class='msg-erro msg-numero'></span>
     </div></p>

        <p><div class="form-group">
          <label for="nome">Nome do Processo</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" value="<?=$cliente->nome?>" placeholder="Informe o Nome">
          <span class='msg-erro msg-nome'></span>
        </div></p>
        <p><div class="form-group">
          <label for="status">Status do Processo</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
         <option value="<?=$cliente->status?>"><?=$cliente->status?></option>
         <option value="Ativo">Ativo</option>
         <option value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
       </select>
       <span class='msg-erro msg-status'></span>
        </div></p>

        <p><div class="form-group">
          <label for="setor">Setor 1</label>
          <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor1?>" class="form-control" id="setor1" name="setor1" placeholder="Informe o Setor Inicial"> Setor 2 <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor2?>" class="form-control" id="setor2" name="setor2" placeholder=" Informe o Setor Final">
          <p><label for="data1">Data:</label>
     <input type="date" name="data1" id="data1" value="<?=$cliente->data1?>" /></p>
     <p><label><p>Observações</p></label>  
     <textarea  name="observ1" id='observ1' rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Informe as observações sobre o processo"><?=$cliente->observ1?></textarea></P>
      <span class='msg-erro msg-setor'></span></div>
       
        <p><div class="form-group">
          <label for="setor">Setor 3</label>
          <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor3?>" class="form-control" id="setor3" name="setor3" placeholder="Informe o Setor Inicial"> Setor 4 <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor4?>" class="form-control" id="setor4" name="setor4" placeholder=" Informe o Setor Final">
           <p><label for="data2">Data:</label>
     <input type="date" name="data2" id="data2" value="<?=$cliente->data2?>" /></p>
     <p><label><p>Observações</p></label>  
     <textarea  name="observ2" id='observ2' rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Informe as observações sobre o processo"><?=$cliente->observ2?></textarea></P>
      <span class='msg-erro msg-setor'></span></div>
       
       <p><div class="form-group">
          <label for="setor">Setor 5</label>
          <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor5?>" class="form-control" id="setor5" name="setor5" placeholder="Informe o Setor Inicial"> Setor 6 <input type="text" value="<?=$cliente->setor6?>" class="form-control" id="setor6" name="setor6" placeholder=" Informe o Setor Final">
          <p><label for="data3">Data:</label>
     <input type="date" name="data3" id="data3" value="<?=$cliente->data3?>" /></p>
     <p><label><p>Observações</p></label>  
     <textarea  name="observ3" id='observ3' rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Informe as observações sobre o processo"><?=$cliente->observ3?></textarea></P>
      <span class='msg-erro msg-setor'></span></div>
     
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="editar">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$cliente->id?>">
       <p> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='botao'> 
          Salvar
        </button></p>
        <a href='listarprocessos.php' class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
    </form>
   <?php endif; ?>
  </fieldset>

 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Quando fizer 1 edição setar o número 1 no banco, quando a pessoa tentar editar de novo, verifica se já está setado o número 1. Se estiver não é possível, caso esteja 0 ainda é possível. Igual o @David Alves disse.

Answer (score 4):

É possível se você criar um campo no seu banco de dados chamado `edicoes` `NOT NULL` e padrão 0 e lá você salva o número de vezes que aquele registro foi editado.

Quando editar a primeira vez, passa de 0 pra 1.

E antes de toda edição, valide se o número de edições daquele registro seja 0, caso contrário não permita que a edição seja feita no próprio `PHP`.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, vou tentar algo aqui!

Comment: O que você não entendeu? Talvez eu possa te orientar melhor.